# What is most efficient way to draw a single character/glyph in a given font at a given point in an android view's canvas?

Tags: android, android-canvas, drawtext

I have a large number of individual characters and their exact pre-computed positions in a view coordinate system, each to be drawn in one of a small number of fonts, in an android/Java canvas belong to a view.

But it appears that there's no low-level way of doing this in Java/android, like there is under iOS, where in iOS the CoreText library provides, e.g., a call:

```
CTFontDrawGlyphs(ctFont, allGlyphIDs[], allPos[], numGlyphs, drawingContext);
```

which is about as fast as possible (the glyph IDs have been precomputed by querying the font).

In android/Java, do I have to create individual text strings for each character, and then call `drawText()` or equivalent?  This seems like it will be very inefficient, given that in my case `numGlyphs` is usually in the thousands.

Comment: While an older article, feels related: [Android’s Font Renderer](https://medium.com/@romainguy/androids-font-renderer-c368bbde87d9)

Comment: Thanks, but I had read that and didn't find it helpful.

Comment: You may want to give some context as to why you are trying to render so many different glyphs on a Canvas however I'm not aware of anything other than `drawText()` as you've found, unless you want to follow the article details about rendering to OpenGL ES yourself.

Comment: I have my own custom layout engine that computes the exact position of every glyph in various fonts on a simulated page of text.  It is currently used in an app for iOS, where `CTFontDrawGlyphs()` does the trick nicely.  I'm porting this technology to android, where the layout of these simulated pages is required to be exactly the same.  Calling drawText() for each character seems way inefficient, but if I use drawText() for longer strings of characters, the glyphs won't be in their exact positions, which can lead to bad looking pages, and other problems.

Comment: Per the article, rendering fonts is an involved pipeline, so if the positions generated by `drawText()` aren't correct I would check if the glyph characteristics are appropriately defined (or use a font format which would render appropriately for your use case). If you are going to draw raw graphics should Android Canvas not work out, be aware that [GAPID](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/diagnose-and-understand-your-apps-gpu_13.html) may be useful. Good luck.